# Функции WinExec, ShellExecute, CreateProcess, system("...") не запускают exe приложение!

Tags: c++, cmd, exe

В лаунчере на С++ должны поочерёдно запускаться несколько других приложений.
Комадны запуска для всех приложений одинаковые - например,

```
WinExec(PathToApp.c_str(), SW_SHOW);
```

Все приложения без вопросов стартуют, кроме одного - EXE-шник, создающий VPN-подключение. Данный файл успешно запускается вручную, из batch-файла, запущенного также вручную, и из `Win+R` -> полный путь к приложению. Попытки запуска из консоли безуспешны. Если из `WinExec()` запустить батник с со сценарием запуска этого EXE-шника, то результата тоже не будет - батник отработает успешно, а VPN так и не создастся.

Как заставить работать этот файл из лаунчера на C++, и чем может быть вызвано такое его поведение (вручную запускается, программно никак)?

Comment: Что значит "Попытки запуска из консоли безуспешны"? Какие коды ошибок возвращают функции? И известно ли Вам, что функции `WinExec` и `ShellExecute` устарели с выходом Windows95?

Comment: Да никаких ошибок. Оно как-бы отрабатывает, а результата нет - VPN не создаётся. Зато по клику или по команде Win-R всё нормально. Насчёт функций известно, но они ведь запускают другие приложения

Comment: Ну так может быть он таки запускается? На основании чего вы заключили, что проблема именно в том, что не запускается процесс, а не, например, в неправильных аргументах командной строки?

Comment: Вы указываете полный путь к программе, устанавливаете правильный текущий путь и анализируете результат, который возвращают функции?

Comment: string Root(argv[0]);
Root = Root.substr(0, Root.find_last_of("\\"));
PathVPN = Root + "\\VPN\\VPN.exe";

cout << "Starting VPN: " << PathVPN << endl;
WinExec(PathVPN.c_str(), SW_SHOW);
...
Далее аналогичные сценарии запуска других приложений, которые запускаются нормально. Пути для них также зараенне формируются по аналогичному сценарию

Comment: Результат, возвращаемый функцией `WinExec` не проверяется, текущий каталог не устанавливается

Comment: "И известно ли Вам, что функции WinExec и ShellExecute устарели с выходом Windows95" - и как вы предлагаете не используя ShellExecute по нажатию кнопки в программе переходить по ссылке в браузере?

Comment: Как говорится, "а ларчик просто открывался... монтировкой...". Перенёс VPN-стартер из папки VPN в корень запуска приложения и system("VPN.exe") таки создало подключение. Почему приложение упорно не хотело запускаться по полному пути из перечисленных в теме функций - так и осталось загадкой.